# Can't connect to remote server via Powershell/WinRm from Build Server

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, winrm

I keep getting this error when the VSTS Release Definition task "Run SQL Server Scripts" is executed:

> [error]System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingTransportException:
>   Connecting to remote server [MY DATABASE SERVER IP HERE] failed with
>   the following error message : WinRM cannot complete the operation.
>   Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is
>   accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception for the
>   WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By
>   default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits
>   access to remote computers within the same local subnet. For more
>   information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

I have:

- Checked the username/password I am using have Administrator privileges (it isnt using a domain)
- Ensured WinRM service is running (on the Build Server, and on the Target Server)
- Ensured the remote server is accessible via WinRM in Powershell console using WinRM quickconfig, which gives me back:

  - WinRM service is already running on this machine.
  - WinRM is already set up for remote management on this computer.
- Disabled the firewall on the Target server (i also tried adding firewall exception for the appropriate IP etc. too to the Windows Remote Management rule)

I must be missing some kind of config, but I don;t know what it is!

Any help much appreciated...

Comment: I end up using this book to help me  in troubleshooting Remoting problems: https://leanpub.com/secretsofpowershellremoting

Comment: > isn't using a domain. **_Why?_**

Comment: Try to run powershell remotely on that target server manually and check the result: https://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use powershell for this something like..

$content = Get-Content -Path "testsqlFile.sql" | Out-String
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance some-ip-address -Database database-name -Username user-name-Password password -Query $content